# Get all children nodes from a parent node neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I'm using neo4j, and I'm trying to look up all children nodes of Sensor Type.

Here is an example of my graph :

Project ---> cluster -----> Sensor

and I want to be placed on a project and find all sensors nodes .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a depth relationship parameter if you know how deep you want to get the nodes.

**Example to get all Sensor nodes related to project 5 based on your example:**

```
Match (p:Project{project_id:5})-[*2]->(s:Sensor) return s
```

you can match every sensor connected at any depth by replacing `*2` by `*`.

See [neo4j documentation on variable length](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.0/cypher/#_variable_length) for more informations.